# Nhibernate get collection by ICriteria

Tags: nhibernate, collections

colleagues. I've got a problem at getting my entity. Mapping:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
           assembly="Clients.Core"
           namespace="Clients.Core.Domains">
     <class name="Sales, Clients.Core" table='sales'>
        <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0">
          <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
          <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Guid">
           <column name="guid"/>
         </property>
        <set name="Accounts" table="sales_users" lazy="false">
            <key column="sales_id" />
            <element column="user_id" type="Int32" />
        </set>
     </class>
```

Domain:

```
   public class Sales : BaseDomain
   {
        ICollection<int> accounts = new List<int>();
        public virtual ICollection<int> Accounts
        {
            get { return accounts; }
            set { accounts = value; }
   }
    public Sales() { }           
   }
```

I want get query such as

```
SELECT * 
 FROM sales s 
 INNER JOIN sales_users su on su.sales_id=s.id 
 WHERE su.user_id=:N
```

How can i do this through ICriterion object?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think the answer should be:

```
public IEnumerable<Sales> GetSalesForUser(int userId)
{
    return session.CreateCriteria<Sales>()
        .CreateAlias("Accounts", "accounts")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("accounts.UserId", "userId"))
        .List<Sales>();
}
```

But I'm confused by your model. It appears that Accounts has a many-to-many relationship with Sales, but you haven't mapped it that way. I'm not sure how to filter an int collection (HashSet in this case). You could try:

```
public IEnumerable<Sales> GetSalesForUser(int userId)
{
    return session.CreateCriteria<Sales>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Accounts", userId))
        .List<Sales>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. One Sales could have many. I try this variant bu got "NHibernate.QueryException: Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Accounts expected type Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[System.Int32], actual type System.Int32"

Comment: There should be a way to filter the HashSet using the Criteria API if you want to stick with your original design. But in the long run it will be better to improve your domain model.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sales = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Sales))
                     .SetFetchMode("Accounts", FetchMode.Join)
                     .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                     .List<Sales>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what about  "WHERE su.user_id=:N"